# data not parsing to view using template render codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a result array from query in a controller, like :

[...]controller/Admin.php :

```
public function user_email()
{
    $this->db->select('user_email');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['email'] = $query->result_array();

    $this->template->render('admin/user_driver', $data, 'admin');
}
```

The libraries/Template.php :

```
class Template {
protected $ci;
public $data;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
}

public function render($view, $viewdata = null, $template = 'frontend')
{
    $html = $this->ci->load->view($view, $viewdata, TRUE);
    $this->data['template'] = $this->parse_blocks($html);
    $this->data['_viewdata'] = $viewdata;
    $this->ci->load->view("template/{$template}", $this->data);
}
public function parse_blocks($html)
{
    $blocks = array();
if(empty($html)) $html = " ";
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('template') as $node) {
        $section = $node -> getAttribute('block');
        $blocks[$section] = $this->DOMinnerHTML($node);
    }
    return $blocks;
}
private function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children  = $element->childNodes;

    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }

    return $innerHTML; 
} 
public function block_exists($blockname = NULL)
{
    if(empty($blockname))
        return false;

    return (is_array($this->data) && is_array($this->data['template']) && array_key_exists($blockname,$this->data['template']));
}
}
```

I `var_dump($email)` in my `user_driver.php` view, but it throws `Undefined variable: email`. The file `user_driver.php` is under `[...]views/admin/user_driver.php`.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Which template library are you using? [Phil Sturgeon's?](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template)

Comment: I'm not sure what it is because i'm asked to modified someone else's code, i added my template code, to be clearer @MackieeE

Comment: Ah! Thank you for including that, it's made it clear - the view data is being reassigned =) `$this->data['_viewdata'] = $viewdata;`

Comment: so which part should i fix?

Answer (score 0):

Your result from the Database is currently returning as a multi-dimensional array result. Change this to `row` if you're expecting just one result:

> `$data['email'] = $query->row_array();`

This will provide you with a single dimensional array to fetch from:

```
$this->db->select('user_email');
$this->db->from('user');
$query = $this->db->get();
$dbresult = $query->row_array();
$emailAddress = $dbresult["user_email"];

$data['email'] = $emailAddress;
```

Comment: @may Including the `$`? Sorry about this! =)

Comment: i'm doing as you suggested, but it still throws error. thanks anw for your help

Comment: @may I just noticed my mistake, apologies for the mis-leading info. I completely missed the `$html = $this->ci->load->view($view, $viewdata, TRUE);`

Comment: @may edited my answer, as I now think it must be the db retrieval!